# Clever way to separate year, month and day from date string?

Tags: java, android, string, date

I have date string, which is in the following format: 2014-Mar-30. I want to separate it into 3 strings: 2014, Mar, 30. Any clever way to do so? (java)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this method:

```
String[] arr = strDate.split("-");
String strYear = arr[0];
String strMonth = arr[1];
String strDay = arr[2];
```

Comment: One quibble: arguably, strYear and strDay should be ints.

Comment: NO: The OP says: `I want to separate it into 3 strings: 2014, Mar, 30` - So he/she wants exactly 3 strings

Comment: OP is wrong.  :-)  Semi-seriously, why would you want the year and date as a String when an int is clearly superior?  You want to compare the day of the month?  A String doesn't work reliably (if they leave out leading 0).  You want to know how many years away is 2222?  A String is extra work.  Java is strongly typed and `int` is clearly a useful type for this case.  I really hate it when programmers turn everything into a String for no good reason.  Or, in this case, a negative reason.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I'd also extend your vision to the month. But who am I to discuss his/her will? S/he wants strings? I give him/her strings... ;)

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way, for your exact case, is to use `String.split('-')`.  (as in @Vyger)

However, a more robust way might be to use regular expressions and search for 4 digits in a row, 3 letters in a row, and whatever is left over (1 or 2 digits).  That way you might be able to handle a lot of plausible alternates like

"Mar-30-2014" or even "Mar 30 2014"

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use something like this.

```
String totalString = "2014-Mar-30";
String yearString = totalString.substring(0, totalString.indexOf('-'));
String monthString = totalString.substring(totalString.indexOf('-') + 1, totalString.lastIndexOf('-'));
String dayString = totalString.substring(totalString.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

Hope this helps :)